# Multiple installations of application with ClusterRole fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm creating a small application which will listen for changes on various resources through the API. For such an task it needs permissions. So I thought I'd create a ClusterRole

```
{{- if not .Values.skipRole }}
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ include "kubewatcher.serviceAccountName" . }}
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - pods
      - events

      - namespaces
      - services
      - deployments
      - replicationcontrollers
      - replicasets
      - daemonsets
      - persistentvolumes
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
      - get

  - apiGroups:
      - batch
    resources:
      - cronjobs
      - jobs
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
{{- end }}
```

I also created a ServiceAccount

```
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ include "kubewatcher.serviceAccountName" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "kubewatcher.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.serviceAccount.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And finally ClusterRoleBinding

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ include "kubewatcher.fullname" . }}
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: {{ include "kubewatcher.fullname" . }}
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: {{ include "kubewatcher.serviceAccountName" . }}
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

My application can interact with the API and everything seems to work just fine. However when I install another instance of my app, as I'm doing when I'm developing it further, I get the below error message.

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRoleBinding "kubewatcher" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "kubewatcher-dev": current value is "kubewatcher"
```

The second instance is installed using the below command where I thought `--set skipRole=true` would let me bind to the already present ClusterRole

```
helm install kubewatcher --namespace kubewatcher-dev helm/ --set skipRole=true
```

Am I on the right path? Is there a better way? I tried to post the relevant parts of my code, please let me know if I should post additional parts

Comment: Have you tried running `helm update` rather than `helm install` while updating the chart second time.

Comment: I don't want to update. I have an instance running in my cluster and I'm installing a new one because of development

Comment: Well in that case, does the name of your `clusterrole`, `clusterrolebinding` and `serviceaccount` resource is different? If not then I suspect it is causing the issue.

Comment: Does you need a cluster-global role, or is creating the role in the same namespace as the service account enough?  That is, can you successfully use (non-`Cluster`) `Role` and `RoleBinding` instead?

Comment: first thing is, for this kind of use cases Role/RoleBinding fits best, with mentioning the namespaces, 2nd, the error says `kubewatcher` ClusterRoleBinding already exists. in these cases, you can either update or delete and reinstall.

Comment: I'm getting permission denied when I'm using Role/RoleBinding. If it's not clear I access resources outside the namespace in which this app runs

Comment: Did you manage to find solution ? Did you take a look https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7418 ?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error according to the error message
Search for information about roles in operator_namespaced.yaml
Then delete these two roles in kubectl and restart successfully

1, **kubectl delete ClusterRole ray-operator-clusterrole**

2, **kubectl delete ClusterRoleBinding ray-operator-clusterrolebinding**